# HTML/CSS Full width header with three columns - 2 fixed one loose

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Problem Statement is as follows, suppose you have an header containing three elements:

```
<div class="logo">...</div>
<div class="search">...</div>
<div class="options">...</div>
```

Both logo and options have absolute withs of 220px and 294px respectively.
Elements layout arrangement is:

```
.logo { float:left; }
.search {float:left; }
.options { float:right; }
```

Now I want to make .search 100% of the window window - 220px - 294px).

The answer to this question should try to seek as answer that do not involve:

- css calc function, like: .search{ width: calc(100% - 200px - 294px); }
- javascript!

I thought about using a table and let the second td => 'search' calculate it's width automatically.
But seems overkill, to use a table for achieving this.

I'm curious about the answer. Don't bother making fiddles, half word is enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use margin for the search div:

```
.logo { float:left;width: 220px; }
.search {margin: 0 295px 0 221px;}
.options { float:right;width:294px;}
```

But for this, html markup should be ordered like this:

```
<div class="logo">...</div>
<div class="options">...</div>
<div class="search">...</div>
```

Comment: Your solutions works, and doesn't use calc, although it makes me hard coded both divs .logo and .options width, and I may have to change those divs width for matters of responsive design. Because I'm not the only developer here, can became hard for others to have conscious of this. Fabrizio Calderan solution seems to solve it this. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use width in percentage. I can't see any problem with this code. Yeah, you may go with @Fabrizio code. But before this check can i use display table...

Comment: Hum, I tried it... doesn't work very well, the elements wrap very easily and I kind of have to be fixed it a lot with media query which I don't want to :) .

Comment: Funny I search that precisely and for me it's acceptable to use display:table as I don't have to support museum-like browsers such as IE6 or 7, and for the remaining I just have to support the latest versions. Thanks once again.

Comment: Ok, Go with the table. :)

Comment: Guess you won ;D. I'll mark your answer as correct right after posting the complete solution here.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about using a table and let the second td => 'search' calculate it's width automatically. But seems overkill, to use a table for achieving this.

right, but you could take benefit of `display: table-cell` ([widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) from all current browsers) without actually using a table

e.g.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="search">search</div>
  <div class="options">options</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#wrapper { display: table; width: 100%; }
#wrapper > div  { display: table-cell;  }

.logo    { width: 220px; }
.options { width: 294px; }
```

**Live example(1)**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwjBqQ

---

Also, on lower screen you may change the position of each block through mediaqueries,

**Live example(2)**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogjMpX

Comment: I experiencing odd paddings with this solution. I set my wrapper height to 60px, and the elements inside don't use more than 60px in height. And for some reason I'm not understanding, the height of wrapper is something like 90px right know, plus elements aligning to bottom of the table-cell divs. I think I'm going to use Bhojendra solution as fallback and mine of 'calc' function as main solution. I didn't ask for a calc solution because I was looking for a fallback solution.

Comment: can I see an example of this issue? could you share a fiddle?

Comment: Sure you can, I've modified your codepen with the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwjBqQ .

Comment: I can't see any height defined in your example

Comment: Sorry, what a mess, I created a full example on your codepen but I didn't fork it, I modified it directly. To be sure it was ok, I saved a copy on notepad and refreshed the page and it was ok. Now I opened your link and only the initial code is there... And I already deleted my backup... It stays for another time, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@BhojendraCLinkNepal give a traditional solution which works on old browsers, but you have to change HTML structure. Another solution works on new browsers with `flex`.

```
<style>
  body {display: flex; flex-direction: row;} /* or the header container */
  .logo {width: 220px;}
  .search {flex: 1;}
  .options {width: 294px;}
</style>
<div class="logo">...</div>
<div class="search">...</div>
<div class="options">...</div>
```

See [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I remeber doing something to the fact of making a "container" div with display-block and then aligning the divs inside just like you would align text. But that was a while back.

You could have aloo at felxbox though http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ... no script ... just css ... that does it similar.

Comment: So, can you answer with the flexfox? If not, this doesn't seem to be an answer to the question.

Comment: A yes ... I see ... you know Leo I am here to help ... posting the link was the right thing. He can read all about it. Copying some of the code from that page and making it look like it just spewed out of your brains ... seeing your post above ... is not my kind of thing.

Comment: The link? How many links are there teaching css, post the whole link then which master the css....

Comment: Yes Leo ... I will do it in the future like you ... pretend it spew out of my brain just NOW.

Answer (score 0):

So the final solution, that seems to me, to be more balanced is:

```
<div class="logo">...</div>
<div class="options">...</div>
<div class="search">...</div>
```

```
.logo { 
   float:left; 
   width: 220px; 
}
.search {
   float: left;
   width: calc(100% - 220px - 294px);

   /* fallback for browsers not support calc() */
   width: auto\9;         /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
   margin-left: 221px\9;  /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 - please ensure this equals .logo:width +1    */
   margin-right: 295px\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 - please ensure this equals .options:width +1 */ 
}
.options { 
   float:right; 
   width:294px;
}
```

Notes on this solution: Browser hacks are not very elegant, although I tend to use them a lot for IE. If you are completely against it, I recommend you to try to emulate calc using the non-standard expression() syntax.

**Thanks everyone!**

Answer (score -1):

Another solution could be like this one : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lekhnath/x785wc71/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search">search</div>
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="options">options</div>
</div> 

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.wrapper .logo{
    position:absolute;
    width:220px;
    top:00px;
    left:00px;
}

.wrapper .options{
    position:absolute;
    top:00px;
    right:00px;
    width:294px;
}

.wrapper .search{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-indent:240px;
}
```

Comment: absolute positioning and text-indent?? Huh, worst solution.

Comment: this solution works and why is that down vote. It is not a competition to satisfy the OP but sharing ideas. Ignore it if you don't like it apply it if satisfy your needs.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just informed you that worst solution.